# Encoding special characters within XML strings

Tags: xml

I have a config file that is XML. It looks like this:

```
<add key="PWD" value="adfas3312<"/>
```

The problem is that `<` at the end of the password. I thought that inside quotes it was fine. but my application croaks reading this config file. I have tried it with a CDATA type approach, tried `&LT;` etc, but none of these seem to work.

What is the correct way to encode it in "" in XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&lt;`

`&LT;` is not the same as `&lt;`

See https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax for more info.